# "suicide" from a window

Tags: situation, mystery

A woman died from falling out of a window of a 100-story building and landing on her back, breaking her neck. While they knew it was from a window, they weren't sure which. They also were unsure if this was suicide or murder.

A detective was called and he performed a small experiment.

He went to the second story, opened the window, took out a coin and tossed it out the window, it landed on heads.

He performed this with every window in every story, opening their windows and tossing a coin out, each time landing on heads.

After he performed this with all the windows, he confirmed that this was a murder and not a suicide.

How did he figure this out?

Comment: From 100 stories up, I think a broken neck would be the least of her worries.

Comment: Assuming there are thirty window on each of a hundred floors (and that the coin was fair) the odds of consistently hitting heads would be astronomical. If anything he's proved that he's in some sort of simulation

Comment: @Richard Or it's simply a two-headed coin.

Comment: @plasticinsect - *"and that the coin was fair*"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because...

> If he *"performed this"* at all the windows, it means he opened all of them. And if all the windows were closed, this wasn't suicide. She couldn't have closed the window after jumping; the killer tossed her out and closed it. *[No idea why the detective had a loaded coin, though. ;)]*

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, so I don't see posting my comment as an "answer;" rather, an observation.  Every time he tossed a coin out the window, it "landed on heads."  That **could** mean that there were always people about, since the coin always hit someone's head. and that this happening when no one was there to witness implied murder.  (No, it's not a good solution.  I just wanted to observe "landing on heads" could be used to mean two distinctly different things.  Maybe someone can use that for a riddle someday?)

Comment: Interesting point. I did wonder about the coin; I heard this riddle before TBH, but it's always possible that this is some new twist on it. *"Maybe someone can use that"* Well, not now that you spoiled the future answer. ;)

Comment: I didn't necessarily mean *here.*. 8-)

Comment: Walt did get the answer correct, but what R. Dye suggested could make a bit of sense. Maybe if the case was that nobody was around to see the dead body and it was discovered later, when every time he dropped the coin, someone went over to see what was going on. It's still wrong as it was sort of tricking about that combined with the fact it brought up how the woman landed on her back, but that is interesting.

Comment: This wouldn't stand up in court. The window might be defective and close on its own or she might have kicked the window-stand on the way out...

Answer (score 0):

The people

> would easily be able to determine wether the body was killed by a falling coin or from falling off a high height, and death from falling was determined. The coin flip is a red herring, it doesn't mean anything. The detective had to *open every window*, it didn't mention anything about the detective finding an open window. Think about what would require two people. *How would the window be closed after the person jumped off and is dead*.

Comment: This is the same as the previous, upvoted, accepted answer - except that it doesn't hide the key part in a spoiler block. Please don't post duplicate answers.

Comment: sorry, my bad, was my first on this site